# Scene slows blender down

Tags: scene

trying to create a scene with mountains,trees ect the more objects I place in the scene that when it starts to slow down I'm trying not to use objects that have a lot of polys is there a way around this?[image]

Comment: Welcome to BlenderSE. Your question lacks vital information to be answered. For example: How are your hardware specs? How many models? How high is your polycount? Maybe a screenshot or two might help? Please take the tour (http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and please also read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Adding complexity to a scene will require more memory and computing power

Comment: my specs gtx 960,eightcore processor,10.0 of ram here is a screenshot of the scene I'm trying to make a cropfield the crops have about 2288 polys a set.

Comment: I don't think there's any true way around. If you have objects with a low poly count (like 250) and you have fifty of them that's still 12500 polys. The only thing you can do is restrict viewport visiblty on particle systems and objects and lower the subsurf.